# Why is my sense of balance bad when I'm sick?

Tags: common-cold

This happens quite often when I have a flu or just a cold. When I'm sitting, I sometimes feel like I am in a very diagonal position, even I am not. To visualize it better, just sit down and lean yourself to the right a bit. That's how I feel when I have a cold while sitting staight upwards. What can cause this? I know it's normal, I just want to know what happens inside the body

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is likely to be problems within the inner ears. One condition which can cause this is Labyrinthitis.

> Labyrinthitis is an inner ear disorder. The two vestibular nerves in your inner ear send your brain information about your spatial navigation and balance control. When one of these nerves becomes inflamed, it creates a condition known as labyrinthitis.
> Symptoms include dizziness, nausea, and loss of hearing. Vertigo, another symptom, is a type of dizziness marked by the sensation that you’re moving, even though you aren’t. It can interfere with driving, working, and other activities ([Pietrangelo, 2017](https://www.healthline.com/health/labyrinthitis)).

There’s no known way to prevent labyrinthitis. Infections and viruses can cause it and you should seek medical advice and receive prompt treatment for any ear infections, and any balance issues, as Labyrinthitis is not the only possible cause.

### References

Pietrangelo, A. (2017). Labyrinthitis. *Healthline*. Retrieved from: https://www.healthline.com/health/labyrinthitis